# Vim mappings made within a file

Tags: vim, command, mapping

When you do a key mapping from within Vim and a certain file, does that mapping get saved for that file (Meaning that when I reopen that file at a later time, the mapping will still hold, but not for other files)?

I have done the remapping in my vimrc before but not like this, so I am unsure.

Thanks

Comment: To make a mapping permanent you need to add it to .vimrc or some plugin/ftplugin file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filetype specific mappings goes to `plugin/ftplugins/<filetype>.vim`. You can keep your mapping there, for instance, `plugin/ftplugn/cpp.vim`.

For you can make a autocmd for whatever mapping you want

```
autocmd FileType cpp map <buffer> <key> ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the filetype-related configuration into `~/.vim/ftplugin/<filetype>/<any-name>.vim`. When you open file or create new file, Vim load all of files named `ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` and `ftplugin/<filetype>/*.vim`. I suggest to use `~/.vim/ftplugin/<filetype>/*.vim` since you can separate files for each categories. For example,

- ~/.vim/ftplugin/html/pluginA.vim
- ~/.vim/ftplugin/html/pluginB.vim

You can separate configuration file for plugins.